# регулярка.Спарсить из списка если до знака '@' меньше N символов.Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Например нужно получить строки с  кол-вом символов от 5 до знака @
Пример списка:

```
1@vmail.ss:123
12@vmail.ss:1@23
123@vmail.ss:123@
12345@vmail.ss:131
123456@vmail.ss:1@31
1234567@vmail.ss:131
12345678@vmail.ss:131
```

На выходе нужно получить :

```
12345@vmail.ss:131
123456@vmail.ss:1@31
1234567@vmail.ss:131
12345678@vmail.ss:131
```

важно работать со всем списком (не построчно читать файл)
Список большого размера.

Comment: `[x for x in l if len(re.split('@')[0]) < N]`

Comment: вы предлагаете считывать построчно , что замедлит работу. Я хочу выдергивать регуляркой подходящие строки сразу из всего файла

Comment: `grep -E '^[^@]{5,}@'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот, если эти символы всегда в начале строки:

```
^[^@]{5,}@.*$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5dtf3

```
1@vmail.ss:123
12@vmail.ss:1@23
123@vmail.ss:123@
12345@vmail.ss:131
123456@vmail.ss:1@31
1234567@vmail.ss:131
12345678@vmail.ss:131
```